# Using Devtools protocol event Page.frameNavigated to get client side navigation redirects

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

The `framenavigated` event in the Devtools protocol doesn't seem to be working the same way as the `framenavigated` event in Puppeteer. If I use the `parentframe` method in the Puppeteer example below I only get the client side navigation redirects which is what I want. If I use the Devtools protocol example replacing the `parentframe` method with `parentId` I don't get anything because the code doesn't get past `parentId`.

How can I use the `framenavigated` event in the Devtools protocol to behave the same way as Puppeteer `framenavigated` and only get the navigation redirect chain?

```
// var url = "http://wechat.com";
var url = "http://yahoo.com";

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
const page = await browser.newPage();

// Puppeteer framenavigated example:
page.on('framenavigated', frame => {
 if(frame.parentFrame() === null) {
console.log("Puppeteer nav frame: ");
console.log(frame._url);
}
});
// Result returns:
// Puppeteer nav frame:
// https://uk.yahoo.com/?p=us

// Devtools protocol framenavigated example:
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Page.enable');

await client.on('Page.frameNavigated', (e) => {
// console.log("Framenavigated event fired");
if(e.frame.parentId === null) {
    console.log("Devtools protocol frame: ");
    console.log(e.frame.url);
 }
});
// Result returns: 
// Either hangs up and times out or finishes but returns nothing

await page.goto(url);
await browser.close();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just took another look at this and figured out the problem, so I'll answer my own question.

The `parentFrame()` method in Puppeteer returns `null` for a frame which is part of the main frame of the page, but parentId in the Devtools protcol returns `undefined` for a main frame. So, I just had to check for an `undefined` or `false` `parentId` value instead. Obvious I know @@.

```
await client.on('Page.frameNavigated', (e) => {
    if(!e.frame.parentId) {
    // if(typeof e.frame.parentId === "undefined") { // works also
    console.log(e.frame.url);
    }
});
```